# How to preview SQLITE db in ionic2 app

Tags: ionic2

I am developing an Ionic2 app. I am using Ionic STORAGE, which uses SQLITE in android. I want to preview that db for debugging. How can I do that. DDMS in android studio shows nothing.

I heard that Stetho is good for android app debugging. But couldn't found any tutorial how to integrate it with Ionic2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Rgds

Answer (score 0):

You can :

- console.log() database values and can see then in android studio debugger
- Use a browser such as chrome in desktop and see database values(may not use sqllite)

more info

> https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/local-storage

Answer (score 0):

Use WebSQL for debugging:

```
import { Injectable } from '';
import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

const DB_NAME: string = 'particulars.db';
const win: any = window;

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

private _db: any;
constructor(private platform: Platform) {
  if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
   this._db = new SQLite();
   this._db.openDatabase({
     name: DB_NAME,
     location: 'default' // the location field is required
   }).then(() => {
     this._tryInit();
   });
  } else {
    console.warn('Storage: SQLite plugin not installed, falling back to WebSQL. Make sure to install cordova-sqlite-storage in production!');
    this._db = win.openDatabase(DB_NAME, '1.0', 'database', 5 * 1024 * 1024);
    this._tryInit();
  }

  _tryInit() {
    //do query here
  }
}
```

See https://gist.github.com/NickStemerdink/64c782807fc31b7bc9b529ad4b1d56d5.